# change the navigation of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

suppose I have an Iframe from other site in my page and there some links to other sites.

I want to do this
when a user click on a link in the iframe instead to navigate to the destination, the page navigate to URL I interest

```
<iframe src="......." width="100%" height="100%" 
    align="middle" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"> </iframe>
```

Comment: for cross domain iframe, that's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are opening a cross-domain iframe it is not possible to alter the contents or for the sake anything on the page. In case you want to achieve a similar effect what you can do is

1) Save the page as HTML 
2) Change the  to the webiste.com so that everything works properly
3) Host this page locally on your server
4) now what you can do is open this page as iframe src so it become same domain iframe, and you can modify whatever you want just writing `$('iframe').contents().<your code>`

It seems like a manual process but you can write a PHP or .NET script to achieve the effect, thats how i had done it and it works perfectly.

Comment: I got it, could you help me in writing it in .Net?

Comment: I have no idea about .NET but i know something about PHP though you have to use enable curl library in your php.ini you have read more about it on php.net. Sorry I won't be help you much on this I am a HTML developer not a PHP or .NET developer. If you understand my answer please vote up.